# Remove group-policy software-installation package

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I use software installation group policy on Windows 2008 R2 to deploy Google Chrome on several client computers. Every time a new release is available, I declare it as a new package that upgrades the previous one, keeping all the previous packages in place. So all the superseded packages are still available in the software installation pane.

The list looks like:

1. Chrome 61 (first install)
2. Chrome 62 (upgrades Chrome 61)
3. Chrome 63 (upgrades Chrome 62)
4. Chrome 64 (upgrade Chrome 63)

Note: Every package has its "Package can upgrade over the existing package" property checked.

Now I need to get rid of the old versions, by right clicking on them and selecting 'All Tasks \ Remove' which requires me to take one of the following choices:

1. Immediately uninstall the software from users and computer
2. Allow users to continue to use the software, but prevent new installations

I don't actually want to uninstall the software, all I want is to remove the superseded packages from the software installation pane, while being able to install new versions in the future. So what do you think I should do?

Is it recommended to remove the GPO entries via ADSIEDIT.MSC and then delete the corresponding AAS files from SYSVOL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I added Chrome 66 to the list, marked it as an upgrade to Chrome 64, and at the same time removed Chrome 61 from the list by selecting the option to "Immediately uninstall the software from users and computer".

Good news is, after a restart, Chrome 66 was installed successfully on domain computers. The removal of a superseded package with the policy of uninstalling it, did not break the upgrade.